# take data array from jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get a simple callback in a direct way

```
$(function(){
        $("input[name='inputs_picture']").on("change", function(){

            var formData = new FormData($("#frn_pic_id")[0]);
            var ruta = "image-ajax.php";
            $.ajax({
                url: ruta,
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(datos)
                {


                    var $directions = datos;
                    var $prov_rut = $directions['prov_rut'];                

                    $("#picture_product").html($prov_rut);
                    $("#ajax_res").attr("style", "visibility: visible");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

var $directions is an array that I create in a very simple way

```
$src = $folder.$name;
    $directions = array();
    $directions["prov_rut"] = $prov_rut;
    $directions["destino"] = $src;
    echo $directions;
```

What I want to do is simply get the values of the array and use them later, I've tryed everything
Thank you in advance for taking a minute to take me out of this blocked.

Comment: One problem here: Array uses index not key, you will get an exception for this `$directions['prov_rut']`

Comment: tryed that, already fixing it, folow the coments of Barmar, the problem was somewhere else, I sent the array in a thousand different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Echoing an array doesn't do anything useful, it just prints the word `Array`. You need to use JSON.

```
echo json_encode($directions);
```

Then in the `$.ajax()` code, use:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

to tell jQuery to parse the JSON result. Then you'll be able to use `datos.prov_rut` and `datos.destino` in the `success:` function.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thank you to bouth Sudhakar and you, bouth ways worked and I tryed them before, like 3 or 4 hours ago, and now I have realized that the problem is the way I try to include it into an append. That's the problem.

Comment: var $directions = JSON.parse(datos);
var $prov_rut = $directions['prov_rut'];    
$("#picture_product").append("<img src='"+$prov_rut+"' style='width: 400px;'>");

Comment: Javascript is not my strong, sorry. Trust me I have tryed lots of things,

Comment: That looks like it should work. Is there an error in the console?

Comment: probably is because I'm using a temporary adress? It's a picture, instead of uploading it, I just want to show it and then later add some info to the picture and upload it.

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /home2/laplatas/tmp/phptGhLkR was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Looks like the problem is that the PHP is returning a bad URL. It needs to return a URL relative to the document root of the server.

Comment: So, I have to upload it anyway and then later decide if delete it in case I don't want it, no?

Comment: I have no idea what you have to do. The problem is in how you assign to `$prov_rut` in the PHP, which isn't shown in the question.

Comment: $prov_rut = $file["tmp_name"]; It's the picture of the file from ajax

Comment: You can't use `tmp_name`. The temporary file is deleted when the upload script finishes. You need to use `move_uploaded_file()` to move the file to a permanent location, and return the URL of that.

Comment: Also, those filenames are absolute, they're not relative to the webserver's document root.

Comment: /home2/laplatas/tmp/phptGhLkR, no Barmar, they are, anyway man, I'll try another way, upload and in case I don't like it then I erase it fom the server. A machine is gonna work, not me

Answer (score 0):

you can use json_encode function to encode convert your php array to json array

```
echo json_encode($directions);
```

To parse the json in ajax success you can use

```
var response = JSON.parse(datos);
```

response will be json object

Comment: Hi  Sudhakar, thank you to bouth Barmar and you, bouth ways worked and I tryed them before, like 3 or 4 hours ago, and now I have realized that the problem is the way I try to include it into an append. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

so what kind of array are we talking here if its single diamention array lek [10,20,30]

then you can do

```
for(var i=0 ;i< datos.length; i++)
{
var val = datos[i];
}
```

if its array of object (json) [{id:1,nam:Rahul}] then

```
$(datos).each(function()
{
 val =  this.objectName
})
```